# same image for two different languages but not for other language

Tags: android

I have an image with french and Spanish text on it. And I have an other image for English.

Do I need to create two drawable folders like `res/drawable-es-xhdpi` and `res/drawable-fr-xhdpi`   and copy the same image in both the folders?

OR

Is their any other option to have a single copy of image for french and spanish?

Comment: It is better to write the text on the run time instead of adding two images

Comment: I've few shapes on it.

Comment: obviously if you have 3 images you have to use 3 folders ... if you have 2 (english and both french and spain on second one) there are 2 ways ... still 3 folders or reference

Comment: Memory wise, it's better to make the picture exactly the same apart from the text. Imagine if you have 100 image and you are supporting 5 languages! That means that you have 500 image which is bad practice

Comment: Tamawy ... don't forget about dpi :), so it will be at least 4 times more (m,h,xh,xxh)

Comment: still I don't understand 3 images? or 2? if 2 and you don't wana make copy of drawable for es and fr: the reference way: https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/e0a9ea5c2ccd48ea7d95

Comment: you aren't required to actually duplicate the files in both locations. Instead, you can create an alias to a resource, as described in the Create alias resources docs - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AliasResources

Answer (score 0):

Try to use aliases.

For example, create a file with the name - icon.xml
Inside this file use icon_es_fr.png image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="icon">@drawable/icon_es_fr</drawable>
</resources>
```

Then put this icon.xml file in drawable-es and drawable-fr folders

Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AliasResources

Answer (score -1):

Always use a generic images that can be used with different languages, then write the text on it OnTheRunTime according to the selected language by the user. In your resources directory create different versions of string.xml files. Use this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) to learn more about supporting different languages.

```
res/
   values/
       strings.xml
   values-es/
       strings.xml
   values-fr/
       strings.xml
```

As I mentioned before "Imagine if you have 100 image and you are supporting 5 languages! That means that you have 500 image which is bad practice". That's why you have to get rid of this idea.

Comment: You can create an alias that points to the same drawable and use this alias in multiple resource folders. 
Docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AliasResources